# Is it possible to change Apache Nifi H2 database to some other DB (like Mysql / postgress)

Tags: apache-nifi

Is it possible to replace Apache Nifi H2 database to some other DB (like Postgres or MySql)

Locked at ApPache Nifi documentations and configurations but couldn't find any

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. The database is meant to be something you don't really need to know much about, it is just another data store on disk like all the other repositories (flow file, content, provenance), it just so happens to be backed by an embedded DB.